Is garbage state necessary in DFA that enforces a particular input combination?
If I have the regex 1(0+1)* for example, then should my DFA have an arrow leading away from the starting state for when the first input is 0? I see that this regex enforces a 1 as the first input.
I feel this can be achieved even without a garbage state, I could just have state 1 changing from state 1 to the end state directly with a reflexive relation.
But if I were to then use this DFA for other purposes (for union/intersection) then would this have any impact on the input that the union/intersection the DFA accepts?

What do you mean by state 1? On what input do you transition from state 1 to the end state? And what do you mean by a reflexive relation? Remember, a DFA is characterized by an alphabet, $\Sigma$, a set of states $Q$, a subset of "accepting" states, $A \subseteq Q$, and a transition function $\delta : \Sigma \times Q \to Q$.

sorry, I was being unclear; what I mean to ask is; if you have the regex q(r+q)* where q and r are the only 2 characters in the alphabet, then does the DFA need more than 2 states? For example, from the starting state, q is the only acceptable transition, but technically r can also be an input. So would you need another state to collect r's as inputs (that wouldn't connect to the end state).

@mike In addition to the accepted answer, this might be helpful too:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133701/why-is-this-automaton-considered-dfa/133704#133704

In short: yes, a DFA for the language $1(0+1)^*$ needs at least 3 states.
In order to prove this, you can use the Myhill-Nerode theorem, which states that the size of the minimal DFA for a language is the number of Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes of the language (if it is finite).
For your language, the classes are $[\epsilon],[0],[1]$. They are all separable from each other. And indeed, the class that corresponds to $[0]$ is intuitively the "rejecting sink".
Having said that, the definition of a deterministic finite automaton is (slightly) open to interpretation. Typically, we require that the transition relation is a function $\delta:Q\times \Sigma \to Q$, in which case you really do need a rejecting sink.
However, some papers/approaches find it more convenient to allow in a DFA that $\delta$ is a partial function, i.e., that you're allowed some "missing" transitions. Technically, these models are identical except the issue with the rejecting sink.

I would like to expand on your last point, for the sake of readers who are just learning about DFAs. It can be cumbersome to list every possible state, character pair to fully specify a transition function. This is especially true if each state only has "meaningful" transitions with a small number of characters. So often the transition function will not be fully specified. You can define DFAs in a way that allows their transition functions to be partial functions, as @Shaull mentioned, or you can state that there is a special state, $G$ (the garbage state/rejecting sink).

This garbage state has the property that for any $(q,a)$ pair such that $\delta(q,a)$ isn't specified, we have $\delta(q,a) = G$. Also, for any character $a \in \Sigma$ we have $\delta(G,a) = G$.
Both definitions of DFAs are equivalent in the sense that you can easily translate between them. So much so that it usually isn't worth specifying which definition you are using. However, if you care about the exact number of states, as you do in your question, then the answer does depend (slightly) on which definition you are using.

Recall that in the case of a DFA, the transition function $\delta: Q\times \Sigma \rightarrow Q$ is a total function. This implies that on each state $q \in Q$, there should be an out-going transition for all input symbols $a \in \Sigma$.
Thus, there must be an out-going transition on $0$ from your start state, which leads to the trap/reject state.
